# WebRequest.KeepAlive property doesn't exist in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to set the KeepAlive property to true, however it doesn't exist.

If I try to set it by adding it in header, I get the following error: This header must be modified using the appropriate property.

Is there any method to set the KeepAlive property to true? Changing the framework isn't an option.

Thank you.

Comment: i know you said its not an option but 2.0 is too old. you really shouldnt use it.

Comment: Now this is crazy... [MSDN documentation on english](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive(v=vs.71).aspx) doesn't have KeepAlive for framework 2.0, but [spanish documentation does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive(v=vs.80).aspx) o.o

Comment: Also, the english documentation states that it is supported in: 4.6, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1   (at the end of the page)

Comment: Well, there's the syntax for 1.1, so it **should** be on 2.0. Dunno what's wrong in your case.

Comment: It's not there. Did you check?